# AngularJS $scope inheritance service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, inheritance, angularjs-service

I'm having some trouble with my code. I can't pass nor console.log the inherited $scope.user in my data service. As I'm having this problem also in another situation which looks the same I guess it's because of the callback.

The main Controller creates the *user*

```
 .controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope, dataService) {
    dataService.getUser(function (response) {
        $scope.user = response.data[0];
    })
```

The dataservice

```
    .service('dataService', function ($http) {
    this.getUser = function (callback) {
        $http.get('mock/user.json')
            .then(callback)
    };
```

The navigation controller (child of mainCtrl):

```
    .controller('navCtrl', function ($scope, dataService) {
    //$scope.user = "test";
    console.log ($scope.user);
    dataService.getNavItems($scope.user,function (response) {
        $scope.navItems = response.data;
    });
```

As you can guess if I set $scope.user manually it works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The promise hasn't resolved yet when navCtrl is instantiated. What you can do is return the promise from $http.get instead of setting scope.user directly in the callback.  And then just wrap the call to getNavItems in the promise.

This is assuming, navCtrl is a child of MainCtrl

```
.service('dataService', function ($http) {
  this.getUser = function () {
    return $http.get('mock/user.json');
  }};

.controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope, dataService) {
    $scope.userPromise = dataService.getUser();
 })

.controller('navCtrl', function ($scope, dataService) {
  $scope.userPromise.then(function(response) {
   var user = response.data[0];
   dataService.getNavItems(user, function (response) {
       $scope.navItems = response.data;
   });
});
```

})

Comment: Sorry I don't get what you mean with *return the promise from $http.get instead of setting scope.user directly in the callback. And then just wrap the call to getNavItems in the promise.* You mean I should return the $http.get value?

Comment: added an example to the answer; notice that in getUser, we return the result of $http.get, which will be a promise.  In mainCtrl, you then just set the promise on scope and in navCtrl, you just operate within context of the promise object that we set on scope.

Comment: Ok, it works. But how can I keep the $scope.user in the main controller as I need the *user* in all sub-controllers.

Answer (score 1):

The Scope will be different for the two Controllers, therefore it won't be defined in one if you defined it in the other. If you want it to work in both, just use the dataService.

```
 .service('dataService', function ($http) {
    this.getUser = function () {
       $http.get('mock/user.json').then(function(data) {
          this.user = data;
       )}
};
```

Then access it in each controller separately, it will be available to both.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like controllers 'mainCtrl' and 'navCtrl' have different scopes. If the scope of 'navCtrl' is a child of the scope of 'mainCtrl', you can access it with `$scope.$parent.user`

To trigger logging when the promise is resolved `$scope.$parent.$watch('user', fucntion(newVal){console.log(newVal)})`

If not, I would suggest to have some kind of context, where you would store the data used by different controllers.

To find a scope you can use `angular.element('[ng-controller="mainCtrl"]').scope()` even in browser console